# Manage HTML list items with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

A section of a HTML list I have:

```
<ul id="listMenu" style="list-style-type:none; margin-left:-50">
    <li> __Menu1
        <ul class="menuitems">
            <li>Item A1</li>
            <li>Item A2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li> __Menu2
        <ul class="menuitems">
            <li>Item B1</li>
            <li>Item B2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li> __Menu3
        <ul class="menuitems">
            <li>Item C1</li>
            <li>Item C2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li> __Menu4
        <ul class="menuitems">
            <li>Item D1</li>
            <li>Item D2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to use jQuery in a separate js file to manage the list.

- Initially, I need to just show the top level menus (__Menu1, __Menu2..).
- When a top level menu is clicked I want to expand and show the sub-items(Item A1 & A2)
- When top level is clicked again the sub-items need to disappear (Possibly use toggle() ?)
- When a sub-item is clicked it needs to alert with its name

I managed to get the sublists to initially not show with:

```
$('ul:gt(1)').hide(); // Hide all submenus initially
```

But past that I really am at a loss with how to access each lists individual items. I know this is all probably simple but I just don't know how to get started and all the other info I've read for is more advanced than I know how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: When you use `$('ul:gt(1)').hide();` are you intentionally showing the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuitems").hide();
    $(".menuitems").find("li").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().show();
        alert($(this).text());
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".menuitems").parent().click(function() {
        $(this).find(".menuitems").toggle();
    });
});
```

Meets all your specs, I think.

See http://jsfiddle.net/BfqhV/2/

Comment: This works very well. I knew it would be relatively simple. I was looking to move the expanding and collapsing of the menu to separate methods. I plan to use

`expand()`
`collapse()`
`explore()`

When I try 

`$(".menuitems").parent().click(function () { 
expand();
});`

and 

`function expand() {
$(this).find(".menuitems").toggle();
}`

It no longer works. How can this be?

Comment: Well, `$(this)` no longer refers to anything useful inside your new function. I'd have the object as a parameter and call `expand($(this));`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

`function expand(element) {
 $(element).children().show();
}`

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Coupled with your method, this will work a charm :)

```
    $(".menuitems").parent().click(function () {
        $(this).find("li").toggle();
    });
    $(".menuitems li").click(function () {
        var li_text_trimmed = $.trim($(this).text())
        alert(li_text_trimmed)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don t get it wrong you need this,

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $(".menuitems").hide(); // hide all sub lists
   $(".menuitems").first().show(); show first one

   //handle click event    
   $(".menuitems").parent().click(function () {
      $(this).find(".menuitems").toggle(); // toogle sub menu every click
   });

});
```